# Multiply and add 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, addition, multiplication

I have two variables one named `$corp_res`p:

```
var_dump($corp_resp)
```

> string(3) "0.3" string(4) "0.35" string(3) "0.4"

Other: `$corp_resp_template`

```
var_dump($corp_res_template)´
```

> string(3) "0.4" string(3) "0.6" string(3) "0.8"

I want to add and multiply the arrays:

```
$total = (0.3*0.4)+(0.35*0.6) +(0.4*0.8) => 0,12+0.21+0,32 

$total = 0.65
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: $sum = 0; 

for ($i==0;  $i<count($corp_resp);){
  $sum += $corp_resp[$i] * $corp_resp_template[$i]; 
  var_dump($sum);                                                                           but is crashing the browser

Comment: @ChristopheCosta this the pseudo-code I showed you [in the chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=34965771#34965771). Look around about some basic for-loop syntax to see how to do it, instead of asking others to write the code for you. And, BTW, the only thing missing in this code is the `$i++` part after the `count()` function (sorry, I thought it was obvious enough to skip it).

Comment: Hello AL.G.,              $sum = 0; 

for($i = 0; $i < count($corp_resp); $i++)

 $sum += $corp_resp[$i] * $corp_resp_template[$i]; 
 
 echo $sum; i try that code and gives 0 final result.

Answer (score 2):

if both your arrays have the same length you can run something like:

```
array_sum(array_map(
    function($resp, $tpl){ return $resp * $tpl; }, 
$corp_resp, $corp_res_template));
```

If the arrays are of unequal length, the tail of the longer array will be evaluated to (number * 0) therefore ignoring them when adding up the final result

Comment: this approach assumes proper conversion of string array values to floats for multplication.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to do it

```
$corp_resp = array("0.3", "0.35", "0.4");
$corp_res_template = array("0.4", "0.6", "0.8");

function add_products($a1, $a2) {
    if (!is_array($a1)) {
            throw new Exception("a1 is not an array");
    }
    if (!is_array($a2)) {
            throw new Exception("a2 is not an array");
    }
    if (sizeof($a1) != sizeof($a2)) {
            throw new Exception("Arrays don't have same number of elements");
    } 

    // both params are arrays and have same number of elements!

    $count = sizeof($a1);
    $multiplied = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
            // we assume that each element is a string representing a floatval so we need to cast as a float before multiplying
            $multiplied[$i] = floatval($a1[$i]) * floatval($a2[$i]);
    }
    return array_sum($multiplied);
}

$val = add_products($corp_resp, $corp_res_template);

var_dump($val);
```

Comment: Hello, i try both codes you sent and try some modifications but is not working.

Comment: @ChristopheCosta "Not working" how? Please be more specific.

Comment: Hello, the problem was in the arrays and use the function array_reduce. Now is working. Thank you for your kindly help.